# BenchmarkDotNet Unable to find Tests when it faces weird solution structure

Tags: c#, benchmarkdotnet

I have problem with BenchmarkDotNet which I struggle to solve

Here's my project structure:

```
- 
    | - Infrastructure
    |        |
    |        | - TestsBenchmark
    |        | - MyInfra.sln
    | - src
            | - Tests
            | - MyProduct.sln
```

`TestsBenchmark` references `Tests` and has only this line of code:

```
BenchmarkSwitcher.FromAssembly(typeof(BasicTests).Assembly).RunAll();
```

but when I run it via `dotnet run -c Release` it throws

`// Generate Exception: Unable to find Tests in ...\Infrastructure and its subfolders. Most probably the name of output exe is different than the name of the .(c/f)sproj`

Previously when my project structure was like this:

```
- 
    | - src
            | - Tests
            | - TestsBenchmark
```

everything worked fine

Reproduction steps (manual), it recreates folders structure, projects, projects relations, solution and add nugets. run it in e.g powershell in some empty folder:

```
mkdir Infrastructure
mkdir src
cd src
dotnet new xunit -n Tests
cd Tests
dotnet add package BenchmarkDotNet
cd ..
cd ..
cd Infrastructure
dotnet new console -n TestsBenchmark
cd TestsBenchmark
dotnet add package BenchmarkDotNet
cd ..
dotnet new sln -n Repro
dotnet sln add .\TestsBenchmark\TestsBenchmark.csproj
dotnet sln add .\..\src\Tests\Tests.csproj
cd TestsBenchmark
dotnet add reference "..\..\src\Tests\Tests.csproj"
```

UnitTest1.cs

```
using System;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using Xunit;

namespace Tests
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        [Benchmark]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("asd");
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using Tests;

namespace TestsBenchmark
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BenchmarkSwitcher.FromAssembly(typeof(UnitTest1).Assembly).RunAll();
        }
    }
}
```

and now inside `Infrastructure\TestsBenchmark`

perform `dotnet run -c Release`

and you'll see

```
// Generate Exception: Unable to find Tests in C:\\Infrastructure and its subfolders. Most probably the name of output exe is different than the name of the .(c/f)sproj

// BenchmarkDotNet has failed to build the auto-generated boilerplate code.
// It can be found in C:\\repro\Infrastructure\TestsBenchmark\bin\Release\net5.0\65ba2c51-e794-4f44-93ab-f811411c86f5
// Please follow the troubleshooting guide: https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/troubleshooting.html
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is you cannot run benchmark with the structure you created and it is intentional.

For the BenchmarkDotNet (and it is a generally good practice) it's required for solution to have following structure

```
   | - root
             |
             | - Project1/Project1.csproj
             | - Project2/Project2.csproj
             | - Project3/Project3.csproj
             | - ProjectInsideFolder
                       | - Project4/Project4.csproj
             | - YouSolution.sln
```

So you can put projects in sub-folders or virtual sub-folders, but the sln file must be  in the root directory.

BenchmarkDotNet needs to find the csproj file for you test project and to do that it uses following algorithm

[image: Root directory search]

Then it searches for the project file in all subdirectories and the root directory itself.

**Note on using same project in 2 or more solutions:**
Don't use the same project in 2 different solutions unless you absolutely have to. It has its consequences and there is also an option to reuse it as nuget-package [you can create your own nuget feed for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview).